# What file triggers Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I need to know which files in the HDFS package, are responsible for hadoop cluster start. (that makes the cluster work when we trigger the start-dfs.sh).

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

The files are NameNode and DataNode classes.

Cheers.